# Expalanation about WPF concept in unleashed WPF 4.0 book

Tags: wpf, 3d, 2d

Can anyone expalin what does the point ( 0,0) refers to  within the CompositionTarget_Rendering .  I could understand that the cube rotates around the Y axis, but what I cannot understand how could it be that the 2D point 0,0 always relates to the same corner of the cube while it's rotating.  In terms of objects, we have the big cube, the small cube, and, as per my undesrtanding, we have a button that is interactive but at the end of the day is USED as brush (not as an object in the 3D sense).  I envision a space where a cube stands up and rotates around a vertical axis Y, but how the placement of the scaled down purple cube winds up with the same relative position with respect to the big cube, namely, one particular top corner of the big cube.   The book says "**the Point (0,0) from the Viewport2DVisual3D’s hosted Button
is mapped into 3D space, and a purple cube is drawn where that Point3D lies in 3D space**"

and I am confused because the sentence implies that the button is situated somewhere on a 2d layer (supposedly behaind the 3D space) but the button is EVERYWHERE in that it is used to "paint" each of the side of the cubes.  What is the best way to envision this 3D space in relation to the 2D layer and the button?

It will also be good to know why the purple small cube revolves around itself, as I could only see the that the trigger rotates the big cube, and the rendering event places the small cube at a fixed position WITHOUT rotating it.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid Name="myGrid">
        <Viewport3D Panel.ZIndex="0">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera Position="3,3,4" LookDirection="-1,-1,-1" FieldOfView="60"/>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <Viewport3D.Children>
                <ModelVisual3D>
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <DirectionalLight Direction="-0.3,-0.4,-0.5" />
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Container">
                    <Viewport2DVisual3D >
                        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
                            <Transform3DGroup>
                                <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="1.5" />
                                <RotateTransform3D>
                                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                        <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="rotationY" Axis="0,1,0" Angle="0" />
                                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                </RotateTransform3D>
                            </Transform3DGroup>
                        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
                        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                            <MeshGeometry3D Positions="1,1,-1 1,-1,-1 -1,-1,-1 -1,1,-1 1,1,1 -1,1,1 -1,-1,1 1,-1,1 1,1,-1 1,1,1 1,-1,1 1,-1,-1 1,-1,-1 1,-1,1 -1,-1,1 -1,-1,-1 -1,-1,-1 -1,-1,1 -1,1,1 -1,1,-1 1,1,1 1,1,-1 -1,1,-1 -1,1,1"
                TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3 4 5 6 4 6 7 8 9 10 8 10 11 12 13 14 12 14 15 16 17 18 16 18 19 20 21 22 20 22 23"
                TextureCoordinates="0,1 0,0 1,0 1,1 1,1 -0,1 0,-0 1,0 1,1 -0,1 0,-0 1,0 1,0 1,1 -0,1 0,-0 -0,0 1,-0 1,1 0,1 1,-0 1,1 0,1 -0,0"/>
                        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                            <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True"/>
                        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                        <Button Name="TestButton">
                            <Button.RenderTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
                            </Button.RenderTransform>
                            Hello, 3D
                        </Button>
                    </Viewport2DVisual3D>
                </ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelUIElement3D>
                    <ModelUIElement3D.Transform>
                        <Transform3DGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="0.2" ScaleY="0.2" ScaleZ="0.2" />
                            <TranslateTransform3D x:Name="cube_translation" />
                        </Transform3DGroup>
                    </ModelUIElement3D.Transform>
                    <ModelUIElement3D.Model>
                        <GeometryModel3D>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                <DiffuseMaterial>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Purple" />
                                    </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                </DiffuseMaterial>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <MeshGeometry3D
                Positions="1,1,-1 1,-1,-1 -1,-1,-1 -1,1,-1 1,1,1 -1,1,1 -1,-1,1 1,-1,1 1,1,-1 1,1,1 1,-1,1 1,-1,-1 1,-1,-1 1,-1,1 -1,-1,1 -1,-1,-1 -1,-1,-1 -1,-1,1 -1,1,1 -1,1,-1 1,1,1 1,1,-1 -1,1,-1 -1,1,1"
                TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3 4 5 6 4 6 7 8 9 10 8 10 11 12 13 14 12 14 15 16 17 18 16 18 19 20 21 22 20 22 23"
                TextureCoordinates="0,1 0,0 1,0 1,1 1,1 -0,1 0,-0 1,0 1,1 -0,1 0,-0 1,0 1,0 1,1 -0,1 0,-0 -0,0 1,-0 1,1 0,1 1,-0 1,1 0,1 -0,0"/>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        </GeometryModel3D>
                    </ModelUIElement3D.Model>
                </ModelUIElement3D>
            </Viewport3D.Children>
        </Viewport3D>
    </Grid>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded" >
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Name="myStoryBoardY">
                    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="rotationY" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
        From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:12" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering;
    }

    static TimeSpan lastRenderTime = new TimeSpan();

    void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Ensure we only do this once per frame
        if (lastRenderTime == ((RenderingEventArgs)e).RenderingTime)
            return;

        lastRenderTime = ((RenderingEventArgs)e).RenderingTime;

        GeneralTransform2DTo3D transform = TestButton.TransformToAncestor(Container);
        Point3D point = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        cube_translation.OffsetX = point.X;
        cube_translation.OffsetY = point.Y;
        cube_translation.OffsetZ = point.Z;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The (0,0) here refers to the 2D coordinates in the Button referential. It is the top left corner of the button. There 6 different visualisations of the same button here but it seems that WPF assumes that the real one is on the first triangle that contains this point of the button.

In this case it is actually the first triangle of the first face. This face is pointing to the negative Z direction (1,1,-1 1,-1,-1 -1,-1,-1 -1,1,-1).

To actually see this you can setup the camera to point to the positive direction so you can see this face of the cube:

```
<PerspectiveCamera Position="0,0,-10" LookDirection="0,0,1" FieldOfView="60"/>
```

Set the light to point in positive direction:

```
<DirectionalLight Direction="-0.3,-0.4,0.5" />
```

Remove the triger to avoid animation and replace (0,0) in with (27, 12) (it is about the center of the button).

You should see the red cube in the middle of the face pointing towards the camera (the neagtive Z face).

[image]

You can also try to remove the first triangle (remove just the first 3 triangle indices). In this case the red cube will move to the positive Z face.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Just to make sure though: that first button along with the other 5 buttons are positioned on an imaginary 2D layer, and the first button you mentioned is not necessarily positioned on the 0,0 coordinate of that imaginary 2D layer; therefore, when the rendering event finds the 0,0 position with respect to the first button it finds the 0,0 position of the button itself and not of the 2D layer on which the button is positioned.  Is that correct?

Comment: Also, the code within the rendering event, is it executed AFTER the big cube is rotated from it's original position or BEFORE ?  If it happens after --which is what my tests seem to indicate-- then is it correct to say that the GeneralTransform2DTo3D instance not only maps the (0,0) point in 2d into 3D space, but it also applies the rotation to  it ?  In other words, how does the transform take place behind the scenes from 2d to 3d, takins into account the rotation of the big cube ?

Comment: For your 1st question: There is no 6 buttons but just one. It is first rendered inside a texture (also called indirect target rendering) and then applied as a texture on the mesh. The point (0, 0) is the top left corner of the button but in this precise case it is also the (0, 0) in the texture too. If this button was wrapped into a grid <Grid Background="White"><Button Margin="30"/></Grid> then the (0, 0) would still be the top left point of the button but the (30, 30) in the texture (because of the margin).

Comment: For the second yes it takes in account all the transformations applied to the big cube. Actually first the (0,0) point is found in one of the triangles of the cube mesh. This gives the projection of the 2D point in to the local 3D space of the cube. Then all the transforms applied between the "Container" and the cube are inverted and applied to this 3D point. So you have the projection of this 2D point in 3D space in "Container's" coordinate space.

Comment: That was very helpful.  I can now see that the transformation logic simply maps the 2D point from the texture to the extent that it decides to do it with respect to that first triangle onto which that texture is applied. It does so relative to the button WITHIN the texture because the TransformToAncestor method was executed from the button itself.  So far this transformation does not take care of the rotation -- it merely finds the 2D point within the  3D space of the unrotated cube...

Comment: ..Then the logic continues on to apply the rotation transform matrix, depending on the targeted angle in the rendering event.  Well done and thanks for sharing your unique knowledge.  Btw, is there any book which you can recommened on with respect to WPF which goes to the levels of details that I seem to aspire to dig into in order to understand and not just accept things as they are ?

Comment: Sorry I can't recommend a book. I think this question was already asked on stackoverflow. if no you should ask it in a separate question.